# Python makes lib error when making FireFox Sync 1.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, synchronization

I've tried to make my own server to new sync service in FireFox. 
I used the following tutorial: https://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync-1.5.html .

When I wanted to check it by using `make test` I got the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jj/syncserver/local/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 403, in loadTestsFromName
    module = resolve_name(addr.module)
  File "/home/jj/syncserver/local/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 311, in resolve_name
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "/home/jj/syncserver/local/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/syncstorage/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mozsvc.config
  File "/home/jj/syncserver/local/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mozsvc/config.py", line 10, in <module>
    from konfig import Config, SettingsDict
  File "/home/jj/syncserver/local/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/konfig/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation
ImportError: cannot import name ExtendedInterpolation
```

What's happened?

Answer (score 0):

`configparser.ExtendedInterpolation` does not exist in Python 2.

You need to use Python 3.

Comment: Oh, but in Mozilla tutorial wrote that need to install python 2.7. Look: https://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync-1.5.html

Comment: OK, it's using a backport of Python 3's `configparser` module, so it should work. I've successfully installed and done a `make test` without any problem. What version of `configparser` is installed (use `pip show configparser`)?